# Continue Postgres transaction with exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception, postgresql, transactions

The **insert** method below insert links on a table in the database (PostgreSQL), but if a error occurs, the rest of transaction is affected and dont works. The exception is because the field URL is unique.

It's possible in PostgreSQL continue the transaction even with the exceptions?

```
for (int i = 0, n = page.getLinks().length; i < n; i++) {
     linkBD.insert(page.getLink(i), idPage);
}            

public boolean insert(Link link, int idPage) {
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO link (id,idPage,url,linkText,"
        + "visited,broken) VALUES(nextval('idLinkSqc'),?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement pstm = Conn.conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstm.setInt(1, idPage);
        pstm.setString(2, link.getUrl());
        pstm.setString(3, link.getLinkText());
        pstm.setBoolean(4, false);
        pstm.setBoolean(5, false);

        pstm.execute();            
        Conn.commit();
        pstm.close();            
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro inserindo link no banco de dados: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Erro no link: "+link.getUrl());
        return false;
    }
}
```

The **error message** in portuguese: transação atual foi interrompida, comandos ignorados até o fim do bloco de transação

The translation of Google Translate, I think is right: ***current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to continue if the failure was inside a [SAVEPOINT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-savepoint.html).  Here's an example in psql:

```
# create temporary table foo (i int primary key);
CREATE TABLE
```

Begin a transaction and insert a row:

```
# begin;
BEGIN
# insert into foo values(1);
INSERT 0 1
```

Start a savepoint, the insert the same row twice.  This will cause an error:

```
# savepoint bar;
SAVEPOINT
# insert into foo values(2);
INSERT 0 1
# insert into foo values(2);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_pkey"
```

Roll back to the savepoint, then insert another row.

```
# rollback to savepoint bar;
ROLLBACK
# insert into foo values(3);
INSERT 0 1
```

Commit and see what's there:

```
# commit;
COMMIT
# select * from foo;
 i 
---
 1
 3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I dont know if this will generate a great performance loss, but creating a savepoint before the insertion of each link and doing a roolbackto it in casa of failure did the transaction was not aborted.

Comment: @Renato, I'm glad it worked for you.  Thank you for the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way around thing, there might be one, but I simply don't know what it is. Once Postgres has an issue in a transaction, it kills the entire thing and your only hope is to restart it. That means you need to ensure that your code will operate correctly before batching it all up (notably things like duplicate primary keys and missing foreign keys and such).

Comment: yeah, or try a rollback if he just wants to keep going and ignore the previous error.

Comment: Well, sure, but that undoes all his work anyway, so he's going to have to restart no matter what.

Comment: It doesn't have to throw it all away and start over if you set a savepoint to roll back to.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the constraint violation (and hence the exception and transaction problem) by changing your `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO link(id, idPage, url, linkText, visited, broken)
SELECT nextval('idLinkSqc'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
FROM link
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT url FROM link WHERE url = ?)
LIMIT 1
```

And then the extra placeholder:

```
pstm.setString(6, link.getUrl());
```

You could also replace your raw INSERT with a stored procedure that would check that the new URL isn't already there before trying to do the INSERT.

**UPDATE**: A better version of the above SQL would be this:

```
INSERT INTO link (id, idPage, url, linkText, visited, broken)
SELECT nextval('idLinkSqc'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
FROM (
    SELECT 1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM link WHERE url = ?)
) AS postgres_needs_this_alias
```

The end result should be the same but this version doesn't need the `LIMIT 1` hack. The idea behind this is to use the inner SELECT to produce one row if `url` is not present (hence the extra nested NOT EXISTS business) and no rows if `url` is present; then, we use the number of rows from the inner SELECT as a counter for how many rows should be inserted in `link`. An `EXISTS` check on an indexed column should be quite fast as well.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I know almost nothing about Java/JDBC.

Two "solutions":

- don't group all insert in one transaction, execute them separately
- take a look at [`SAVEPOINT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html)s

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
INSERT INTO table (column list)
SELECT v.* FROM (VALUES (....), (....), (....)) v
     LEFT JOIN table t ON t.t_unique_column=v.column1 -- choose the matching column
     WHERE t.t_unique_column IS NULL
RETURNING *
```

This will allow you to insert a bulk of rows without exception checking for each row, and the RETURNING clause gives you back what was inserted, sequence generated PKs, etc. It is the fastest solution (besides COPY).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the commit outside of the try block (maybe to a finnaly block)?
And maybe it has something to do with returning false (have you tried to see it the code isn't checking for this boolean at a later time and doing some kind of rollback if it's false?)

Comment: After looking more carefully at your code and the exception, I think will need to start a different transaction before the insert, that way, it it fails, it will correctly stop only this atomic transaction (but be ware of a performance overhead associated with starting and committing a lot of transactions).

Answer (score 0):

The problem shouldn't be how to handle exceptions but rather how to prevent exceptions. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql) should give you information how to gracefully ignore inserts that would fail because of duplicate keys.